# How to get sqlite to connect when using sqldf?

Tags: r, sqlite

```
library(sqldf)

# Function to compare racer's NetTime with racer in front of him/her
NetTime_pos_fun <- function(x){
  race_data <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY Place ASC")
  timeDiff <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(race_data$NetTime_num)){
    difference <- race_data$NetTime_num[i] - race_data$NetTime_num[i+1]
    timeDiff[i] <- difference}
  return(length(which(timeDiff > 0)))
}
# Function to compare racer's GunTime with racer in front of him/her
GunTime_pos_fun <- function(x){
  race_data <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY Place ASC")
  timeDiff <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(race_data$GunTime_num)){
    difference <- race_data$GunTime_num[i] - race_data$GunTime_num[i+1]
    timeDiff[i] <- difference}
  return(length(which(timeDiff > 0)))
}
gender <- c("Female", "Male")



NetTime <- c(NetTime_pos_fun(female_racers), NetTime_pos_fun(male_racers))
GunTime <- c(GunTime_pos_fun(female_racers), GunTime_pos_fun(male_racers))
comp <- data.frame(gender <- c("Female", "Male"),
NetTime <- c(NetTime_pos_fun(female_racers), NetTime_pos_fun(male_racers)),
GunTime <- c(GunTime_pos_fun(female_racers), GunTime_pos_fun(male_racers)))
comp <- setNames(comp, c("Gender","NetTime Comp count","GunTime Comp count"))
#Comparison table
comp %>%
  kbl(caption = "NetTime vs GunTime racer position comparison", format = 'markdown') %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")
```

Error #1

```
Error in connection_connect(dbname, loadable.extensions, flags, vfs, extended_types) : 
  object '_RSQLite_connection_connect' not found
12.
connection_connect(dbname, loadable.extensions, flags, vfs, extended_types)
11.
initialize(value, ...)
10.
initialize(value, ...)
9.
new("SQLiteConnection", ptr = connection_connect(dbname, loadable.extensions,
flags, vfs, extended_types), dbname = dbname, flags = flags,
vfs = vfs, loadable.extensions = loadable.extensions, ref = new.env(parent = emptyenv()),
bigint = bigint, extended_types = extended_types)
8.
.local(drv, ...)
7.
dbConnect(m, dbname = dbname)
6.
dbConnect(m, dbname = dbname)
5.
sqldf(x = "SELECT * FROM df ORDER BY Place ASC")
4.
do.call(FUN, mcListE, envir = p)
3.
withVisible(do.call(FUN, mcListE, envir = p))
2.
fn$sqldf("SELECT * FROM df ORDER BY Place ASC")
1.
NetTime_pos_fun(female_racers)
```

---

Error #2

```
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
2.
sqldf("SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY Place ASC")
1.
NetTime_pos_fun(female_racers)
```

I've tried setting the options for sqldf. My understanding is it uses sqlite for the db. I changed it to mysql and then ran into authentication issues since I don't set the DB connection.

Comment: The error messages indicate that it is trying to use SQLite, likely because the library(RMySQL) statement is missing. Also please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page and note that it asks for a complete reproducible and minimal example that others can run. Reduce the code to just what is needed to illustratate the problem and ensure that others can run it.